# JQuery Change Event Problem

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with Change event . I want to do a request using ajax every time that the input value changes = keyup , past , cut.... the change event in jQuery is too slow !!

```
$("#Password").change(function (){
    $.post("register.php", {do : 'password', pass : $(this).val()}, function (data){
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Thx Every One I Opened A Plugin Called **Elastic** and I find what I am looking for :

```
$(Your Selectors).bind('keyup change cut paste', function(){
    //do things
});
```

It's Perfect ^^ !!

Comment: Ummm... what code to you have right now?

Comment: $("password").change(function(){//....});

Comment: Please put your full code in the question or else it is a useless and `not real` question

Comment: The `change` event is fired when the element loses focus after changing. You may want to look at the `keyup` event.

Comment: But value can be changed without Keyup 4exemple paste

Comment: @Isaam what type of dom element is `#Password`?

Comment: @Issam Zoli - Then bind to both the `keyup` and `change` events.

Comment: @James -- that is what i did in my answer below.

Comment: @Neal - Ahh, yes, I didn't scroll down to look at the answers! +1 to your answer.

Comment: @James - do you understand what the OP means on the comment to my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a few things to cover all bases if you want:

```
$("#Password").bind('action_taken',function (){
    $.post("register.php", {do : 'password', pass : $(this).val()}, function (data){
        alert(data);
    });
}).blur(function(){
       $(this).trigger('action_taken'); //call action_taken on blur
}).change(function(){
       $(this).trigger('action_taken'); //call action_taken on change
}).keyup(function(){
       $(this).trigger('action_taken'); //call action_taken on keyup
});
```

Comment: Doesn't catch past event -__-' !!

Comment: @Neal - I have a feeling he meant "paste" (see comments on question). @Issam - If you paste something into the field, the `change` event will still fire when it loses focus.

Comment: Thx Bro I Think U Know What I Mean Now ^^ !!

Comment: @Issam -- on lose focus is the `.blur()` event, i think thats what you wanted -- see my answer

Comment: No I Post The Answer , I Need To Catch Every Single Change In The Value Which Can Be By Typing,Cuting Or Pasting !!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can have an alternative of storing input value in a variable, and checking for keyup (and comparing the current value to the previous value) only when that field has focus to trigger your ajax request.

you can get the element in focus using `document.activeElement` or for jquery 1.6+, the `:focus` selector

for the problem of pasting with mouse, you can repeat the eventlistener for left mouse click